# AVCaptureSession Video Not Saving

Tags: ios, photo, avcapturesession

In my iOS app, I use AVCaptureSession and an overlay to record video.  However, nothing is getting saved to my photo album.  What am I doing wrong here?  When I run the NSLog the console shows the expected path, but it runs the didFinishRecording code as soon as the view loads, and not at the end of recording.

```
//
//  LiveCam.m
//  P3 Media
//
//  Created by Candace Brassfield on 7/29/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 316 Apps. All rights reserved.
//

#import "LiveCam.h"

@interface LiveCam ()

@end

@implementation LiveCam
@synthesize session;
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d hh:mm:ss a"];
    // display in 12HR/24HR (i.e. 11:25PM or 23:25) format according to User Settings
    NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
    NSError* error4 = nil;
    AVAudioSession* audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:&error4];
    OSStatus propertySetError = 0;
    UInt32 allowMixing = true;
    propertySetError |= AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OtherMixableAudioShouldDuck, sizeof(allowMixing), &allowMixing);

    // Activate the audio session
    error4 = nil;
    if (![audioSession setActive:YES error:&error4]) {
        NSLog(@"AVAudioSession setActive:YES failed: %@", [error4 localizedDescription]);
    }
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    self.session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    [self.session beginConfiguration];
    self.session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720;
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    NSError *error = nil;

    AVCaptureDevice *audioCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    NSError *error2 = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioCaptureDevice error:&error2];


    AVCaptureDevice *device;
    AVCaptureDevicePosition desiredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
    // find the front facing camera

    device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];


    // get the input device
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];




    AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *movieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];

    NSString *archives = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"archives"];
    NSString *editedfilename = [[@"ComeOnDown" lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSString *datestring = [[editedfilename stringByAppendingString:@" "] stringByAppendingString:currentTime];
    NSLog(@"%@", datestring);
    NSString *outputpathofmovie = [[archives stringByAppendingPathComponent:datestring] stringByAppendingString:@".mp4"];
    NSURL *outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:outputpathofmovie];
    [self.session addInput:audioInput];
    [self.session addInput:deviceInput];
    [self.session addOutput:movieFileOutput];
    [self.session commitConfiguration];
    [self.session startRunning];




    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:self.session];
    previewLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;

    CALayer *overlayLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CALayer *overlayLayer2 = [CALayer layer];

    UIImage *overlayImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LiveBorder.png"];

    [overlayLayer setContents:(id)[overlayImage CGImage]];
    overlayLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
    [overlayLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

       CALayer *rootLayer = [self.view layer];
    [rootLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [previewLayer setFrame:[rootLayer bounds]];
    [rootLayer addSublayer:previewLayer];
    [rootLayer addSublayer:overlayLayer];
    [rootLayer addSublayer:label2.layer];
        movieFileOutput.movieFragmentInterval = kCMTimeInvalid;

    [movieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:outputURL recordingDelegate:self];



    //self.session = nil;
    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:
                                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Failed with error %d", (int)[error code]]
                                                            message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];

    }
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
}
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;

}

-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)fileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections {

}
-(void)video:(NSString *)videoPath didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo{
    NSLog(@"Finished with error: %@", error);
}
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error {
    //finished
    NSString *proud = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[outputFileURL path]];
    NSLog(@"Finished%@", proud);

    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(proud, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError: contextInfo:), (__bridge void *)(proud));
}

-(IBAction)goBackNow {
    [myAVPlayer stop];

    [self.session stopRunning];
    // [captureView performSelector:@selector(stopRecording) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];

    NSString *outputPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0], @"output.mp4"];
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputPath, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError: contextInfo:), (__bridge void *)(outputPath));

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;

    //[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
-(void)allDone {

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this code after Path to video and check:

```
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(url.path, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

And add this method in your viewcontroller

```
- (void)video:(NSString *)videoPath didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo {
    if (error == nil) {
       [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Saved to camera roll" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    } else {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failed to save" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }
}
```

Hope it works for you.!

Comment: I added that, and it popped up the alert the moment the view appeared saying it saved it to camera roll, AND when it should have popped up after I clicked stop.  However, neither time actually saved the video.